# 'MvvmCross/MvvmCross.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, mvvmcross

I got error "MvvmCross/MvvmCross.h file not found" as below screenshot when building in XCode.
The project is buildable in Visual Studio Code for Mac. But when building this in XCode, I got the error as mentioned.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfnoe.png)

Answer (score 0):

MvvmCross is a C# project. Xcode does not build those.